# Why isn't my header showing up on certain browsers?

Tags: html, css, banner

On Safari, the following code works perfectly for displaying my banner, but for some reason on all other browsers the banner just doesn't show up. I've used the inspect element features on the browser and it seems to be all there but it is like it was never there.
Here is the HTML and corresponding CSS for the header. Am I doing something wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="int-site-container">
    <div id="int-site">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#int-site-container{
margin: 0;
}
#int-site{
    background: url(/images/<mysite>-introbanner.png) center top no-repeat;
    height:inherit;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling around I found out why the banner would not show up. Since I was using a containing `div` that didn't have a defined height, most browsers would not create space for it so it just remained a div of 0 height. To fix this, I changed the containing div to the height of my banner image

```
#int-site-container{
margin: 0;
height:166px; /*this was the line I needed*/
}
#int-site{
    background: url(/images/<mysite>-introbanner.png) center top no-repeat;
    height:inherit;

}
```

Comment: if you just use a static image instead of background, you don't have to set the height.